# Is UK still in the EEA?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

Now that Brexit happened, is UK still in the EEA?

Comment: Till end of 2020 GB is under all EU laws

Comment: @Trish except for those explicitly mentioned in the withdrawal agreement.  That includes new EU laws enacted during the transition period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 23:00 GMT on 31 January 2020, the UK is no longer a member of the European Union.

But there is a 'transition period' or 'implementation period' until 31 December 2020. During this period the UK is 'in' the EU single market and customs union.

For practical purposes it is 'in' the EEA until 31 December 2020.

By the way, Switzerland is not a member of the EEA but it is in the EU single market.

Comment: Oh!! I was convinced Switzerland was not part of the EU, but part of the EEA!! Just checked, and you're absolutely right.
Thanks very much! :)